# How to count date on the x axis and plot in graph

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I am new to VBA. I am trying to write a script that counts the dates in a row (until the row ends) and plot the dates on the x-axis with the corresponding frequency the dates appear on the y-axis.

For example if "1/1/14" appears 3 times, the line would start at 3 (y-axis) under "1/1/14" (x-axis)

Right now, I only know how to write a script that reads an entire row, formats the date, and outputs the date in a message box. I know its not much but I don't know where to go from there. Here is the code:

```
              Sub test1()
              Dim n As Integer

              For n = 2 To 8
                  MsgBox Format(Cells(n, 2), "MM/dd/yyyy")
                Next
              End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

this applies to "any help". So far, it counts any data found in row "D". You get the values once liste in "E" and the number in "F". To have it working, you'll have to put the first two values manually in "E1" and "E2" (...OK, this is not perfectly working, then...)

```
Sub D()
'this selects your list in col "D" and puts every value once in "E", then counts it in "F"
'however, it only works so far if anything is in "E1" and "E2".
    Dim s As Range, Cell As Range, rng As Range
    Set s = ActiveSheet.Range("D1", ActiveSheet.Range("D65536").End(xlUp)) 'put your existing values here
    Set f = ActiveSheet.Range("E1", ActiveSheet.Range("E65536").End(xlUp)) 'here youre values only once
    For Each Cell In s
        Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("E1", ActiveSheet.Range("E65536").End(xlUp)).Find(Cell.Text) 'ActiveSheet.Range("E1:E1000").Find(Cell.Text)
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                ActiveSheet.Range("E1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = Cell.Text
                ActiveSheet.Range("E1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1) = 1
            Else
                rng.Offset(0, 1) = rng.Offset(0, 1) + 1
            End If
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: ipoood, since you've been online after I posted this - no comment at all? So if this had nothing to do with what you wanted - could you try again to describe, what exactly you do want, then? Generate a diagram with this data shouldn't be very difficult, I think